# asp.net chart control not working on mono 3.6

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, freebsd

I'm using mono 3.6 on freeBSD 10 and I want to run asp.net pages on mono. The problem is when I load a project containing any type of Ms chart control this error appears:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
```

I found and copied (manually or by add reference) required dlls to my project but nothing changed, I also copied those dlls in /usr/local/lib/mono/[dot net version] dir of freeBSD and didnt work. 
Meanwhile I tested this is both in website project and web application!
The only problem I have on mono is chart control an I have to use just ms chart control.
Has anyone ever encountered with this damn trouble?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deinstall and install mono again with the consideration that correct setup configuration be done!. It can be accomplished by ./configure command in the mono port directory.